# Problems using Spanish characters in image URL

Tags: html, angular, character-encoding

I have a table in my Angular 6 app, that is displaying contents from a service. Within the table, I have two columns that use the exact same property. `{{standing.teamName}}`

The first column displays the Team Name as a text and it works correctly. 
e.g.: España

```
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Equipo">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Equipo</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let standing">{{standing.teamName}}</td>
    </ng-container>
```

The second column uses the exact same value to parametrize the img source.

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="img">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let standing"><div><img mat-card-avatar src="../../assets/Flags/{{standing.teamName}}.png" alt=""></div></td>
    </ng-container>
```

In this case, the issue I get is: 
GET http://localhost:4200/assets/Flags/Espa%C3%B1a.png 404 (Not Found)

I've tried naming the file exactly like that Espa%C3%B1a.png to see if It could be found but is not.

I'm getting the same problem with accents and other Spanish characters and I can't figure out why it is working in one, but not in the other.

Comment: It's url encoding the ñ as it's not a url safe character. It's not an issue to display it in the HTML, but it is an issue when making HTTP requests

Comment: Does the URL work if you just type it in the browser location bar? Are you on Windows?

Comment: No, I'm on MAC. I can't really try the browser thing since I'm on angular using a router module but trying the GET with a rest client I get the same result. 
http://localhost:4200/assets/Flags/Argentina.jpg works perfect
http://localhost:4200/assets/Flags/España.png says: Cannot GET /assets/Flags/Espa%C3%B1a.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify you have the following meta atrribute in the head of your HTML:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Verify the character set of your database/table is set to `UTF-8` too.

That should be enough to make it work.

---

However, I personally would recommend you to **use only safe characters** in your URIs, **replacing the `'ñ'` by `'n'`** and the vocals with accent with **vocals without accent**. I also try to **avoid uppercase**.

That would avoid this kind of problems, help your SEO, and make your code more portable, maximizing the compatibility between servers and browsers.

In the following external link, you can read some suggestions of the Spanish community about this issue :

http://www.forosdelweb.com/f64/url-amigables-realmente-no-deben-usar-acentos-ni-e-872760/

Comment: yeah, I was trying to avoid that since these values are coming from the database and I will need to modify this all the way down but seems that is actually the "easy" way haha thx

Comment: do you have those URIs/filenames,  encoded in your database using UTF-8 ?

Comment: Not really, I don't have the assets defined in my database. I was rather changing the actual assets name to match the values coming from the DB but seems like the problem is on the URIs as you mentioned. I will add an extra column on my teams tabl with something like en_name since I will be using this approach for more stuff. thx

Comment: Using UTF-8 is considered a good practice. It will prevent many unexpected and nasty situations to happen, and your life is gonna be much easier ;)

Comment: I have it yes but for some reason http requests get broken